# weak convergence in $l^p$ implies bounded and pointwise convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $1<p<\infty$, $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq l^p(\mathbb{N})$ such that $u_n$ converges weakly to $u\in l^p(\mathbb{N})$. Prove that

(1) $(u_n)$ is bounded and (2) for all fixed component $j\in n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_{n,j}=u_j$ (in lecture we called it "pointwise convergence of sequences").

My questions are: (1) is "$(u_n)$ bounded", i.e. $\|u_n\|<\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ already satisfied because $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq l^p(\mathbb{N})$?

For (2) it is to show that $|u_{n,j}-u_j|\to 0,\; n\to\infty$ for fixed $j\in\mathbb{N}$. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: $u_n$ is itself a sequence, say $u_n=(u_{n,k})_{k=1}^\infty$. $\{u_n\}$ bounded means $\|u_n\|_p^p=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|u_{n,k}|^p\le M$ for some $M$ and all $n$.

Answer (score 3):

(1) No doubt "$(u_n)$ is bounded" means $\sup_n\|u_n\|_p<\infty$. I'd haul out the Uniform Boundedness Principle.

(2) For fixed $j$, test the weak convergence of $(u_n)$ against the element $v\in l^q$ defined by $v_i=1$ if $i=j$, $v_i=0$ if $i\not=j$.